# How would can i keep horizontal divs (3 in a row) with margins inbetween them inline with wrapper?

Tags: css, html

Basically I have three divs in a row, each with a 10px margin between them in a responsive layout.

Currently the divs have margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; in them to keep them spaced apart. However I would like to keep it inline with a wrapper, in short, with no margins at the end of where the beginning of the first div and end of the last div meet the wrapper, so it fits perfectly within the wrapper.

How could I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Code:

CSS -

```
#frontpage {
float: left;
width: 32.33%;
margin-left: 0.5%;
margin-right: 0.5%;
```

}

HTML in Wordpress output:

```
    <aside id="frontpage" class="widget widget_text">
<h3 class="widget-title">Quickplay</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>Content Here</p>
</div>

    <aside id="frontpage" class="widget widget_text">
<h3 class="widget-title">Quickplay</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>Content Here</p>
</div>

    <aside id="frontpage" class="widget widget_text">
<h3 class="widget-title">Quickplay</h3>
<div class="textwidget"><p>Content Here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your actual code?

Comment: why dont you want margin at start of first and end of last div? will it not look little weird?

Comment: @StackUP The container for the section is already centred to where I want it in the design. I simply need the margins inbetween them as margins on the ends of each area will just push it in even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```css
#wrapper > div {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Then, use this CSS instead:

```css
#wrapper > div {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#wrapper > div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zero the margins with the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child) and [`last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child) selectors:

```
.mydiv:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.mydiv:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you devide then in 33% it will be 99 + margin/padding it will cross 100%. so the third div will come in next line. you will have compormise with width. check out if it works. though it is not perfect but still a lot closer to what are you looking for.

```
<style>
  #one{display:inline; float:left; width:32.7%; }
#two{display:inline; float:left; width:33%;  margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;}
```

```
<div id="big_wrapper">
 <div id="one"> this is first div and your content goes here. this is first div and   your content goes here</div>
  <div id="two">this is second div and your content goes here. this is second div and your content goes here</div>
  <div id="one">this is third div and your content goes here. this is third div and your content goes here/div>
```

it works there is slight difference in width but that you cant find out.